# belong_to association and ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey in Rails 5

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, belongs-to

My application has two models: `Service` and `User`. A service may have and assigned **driver** or not. I have implemented this as:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

and:

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    belongs_to :driver, class_name: "User", optional: true
end
```

Note that since a particular service may or may not have a driver, I have marked the association as `optional`. And I don't have any pointer from the `User` model to  `Service`.
I have the following migration implementing this association:

```
class AddOPtionalDriverToService < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :services, :driver, references: :users, index: true
    add_foreign_key :services, :users, column: :driver_id
  end
end
```

The relevant part of my schema when I run the migration is:

```
create_table "services", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "destination"
    ....
    t.text     "comments"
    t.index ["driver_id"], name: "index_tdy_requests_on_driver_id", using: :btree
  end
...
  add_foreign_key "tdy_requests", "users", column: "driver_id"
end
```

My problem is that when I try to create a new service without a driver my `params` contains a value of `"0"` for the driver:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"kVC53huZYZxuF4akSiqkGkSvoo5p2f4dQ==", 
  "service"=>{
    "destination"=>"Some where", ... , 
    "driver_id"=>"0", 
    "comments"=>""}, 
  "commit"=>"Create Service"}
```

But since driver_id is "0" I get the following exception:

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: insert or update on 
table "services" violates foreign key constraint 
"fk_rails_15497e1c36" DETAIL: Key (driver_id)=(0) is 
not present in table "users"
```

This makes lots of sense but the funny thing is that I have discovered this when I move from SQLite to PostgreSQL because **it was working fine with SQLite**. At least the application was doing what I wanted to do. I'm using Rail 5.0.2.

I would like to know how can modify my models or migrations to avoid this exception. Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I have just realized the solution. Something that I didn't say was that I enter the driver using a select element. Since the driver is optional I was adding and "empty" using:

```
<option value="0"></option>
```

changing to:

```
<option value=""></option>
```

solves the problem.

I'd prefer to remove the question since doesn't offer any value.